# Node's orientation is wrong when I make a full circle

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I need that node always looks to the camera, I make this by

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.node.orientation.y = sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation.y
    }
}
```

but when I try to make a full circle (change direction of the camera to the opposite) this value becomes wrong. I tried to use `SCNBillboardConstraint()`, but with it `orientation` of node keeping 0 value, and I need to know the angle, so, this isn't suited me.

I need to change only Y rotation, X and Z need to be 0

Edit: I've noticed that I need to use node.presentation.orientation.y when I use constraint, but this is still working incorrectly with angles against start angle near PI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, instead of `SCNBillboardConstraint` try to use `SCNLookAtConstraint`.

`SCNLookAtConstraint` object automatically adjusts a node’s orientation so that it always points toward another node.

If SCNLookAtConstraint is not useful, then this is a gimbal lock issue. Gimbal lock is the loss of one dof in a three-dimensional mechanism. There are two variables in SceneKit: `eulerAngles` (intrinsic euler angles, expressed in radians, represent a sequence of 3 rotations about the x-y-z axis with the following order: z-y-x or roll, yaw, pitch) and `orientation` (node’s orientation, expressed as quaternion). You use the last but...

SceneKit uses unit quaternions, whose components satisfy the equation:

```
x*x + y*y + z*z + w*w == 1
```

I suppose your camera doesn't rotate correctly because you use only one component of quaternion structure (without the fourth significant component in the vector, what is `w`).

> To get rid of incorrect camera's behaviour use all components of quaternion (expressed in `SCNVector4`, where `x-y-z` values are normalized components, and the `w` field contains the rotation angle, in radians, or torque magnitude, in newton-meters).

```
self.node.orientation = (sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation)!
```

All corresponding nodes must be of the same type.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of `orientation`. I tried to use SCNBillboardConstraint, but use only Y component of orientation after rotation, but should use whole `orientation`